# Pass Session Variable with hyperlinkfield in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, session-variables

here is my gridivew:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBatters" runat="server" DataKeyNames="playerID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="nameFull" HeaderText="Player" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Pages/individualPlayer.aspx" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="g" HeaderText="G" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="avg" HeaderText="AVG" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="obp" HeaderText="OBP" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="slg" HeaderText="SLG" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ops" HeaderText="OPS" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rc" HeaderText="RC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="h" HeaderText="H" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="doub" HeaderText="2B" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="trip" HeaderText="3B" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="hr" HeaderText="HR" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rbi" HeaderText="RBI" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to pass the datakeyname "playerID" with the hyperlinkfield to the individualPlayer page.  Id prefer to not use query strings, so i was thinking there must be a way to make the datakeyname a session variable.  i can then use that variable for what i need, dont need query string.  i just cant think of how to go about doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this you can also bind anchor tag from code behind as well. as you know that Hyper link is nothing but a anchor tag. so in this case you can bind anchor tag from code behind as

```
<a href='~/Pages/individualPlayer.aspx?Id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'>Player</a>
```

try this and if you want to put link name while binding you can also write like this

`<a href='~/Pages/individualPlayer.aspx?Id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "`PageName") %>

try this.

Answer (score 0):

HyperLinkField will not work for this.  What you want is a command field with a button type of link.  On clicking the command, the RowCommand event fires on postback to the server, you'll write the session value, then use Response.Redirect.  That is how this would have to be done.

Comment: the command field does not have a data field.  i would like to be able to click a specific field in the row, is it possible to fire the rowcommand that way?